# Pega 7 CRM web app memory consumption

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory, pega

I am checking for the first time a CRM application built on top of Pega 7 (7.1.7)

As a first test run, I am encountering a hug memory consumption by the browser, hwen simply navigating between menus. The iexplorer.exe for example launches the web app at 100 Mbytes, and it reaches 1.3 Gbytes after 10 minutes of working with the system.

1. Did anyone ever worked on Pega 7 application?
2. Is it normal for Pega 7 web apps to consume such high levels of RAM on the client side? and increasingly consume without garbage collection?
3. Could there be any settings on the browser that I must configure properly? but i doubt since both IE and Chrome have the same memory consumption

Appreciate any feedback

Thanks

Comment: Are you in the developer portal? if so, it could be the "Live UI" feature. Also features like Pega Social have an impact on the final product.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll test it out next time I am on the environment and let you know if this is an acceptable solution

Comment: Hi again ramayac, The live UI button appears on the bottom of the app, but the memory leaks are detected without having it activate while running the tests

Answer (score 1):

Run tracer when the issue is occurring. Make sure that you have the below settings enabled for tracer to find performance issues :-

1. Enter the number of trace events to 0.
2. Enter the events to be traced checked for DB query, DB cache ,Alerts , all declarative rules and Stream rules.
3. After running tracer with the issue scenario, save as the tracer to your desktop (as XML file by default) and then open the tracer using trace viewer tool from PDN.

This should give you exhaustive inputs on what is the primary problem.

Also, you can use PLA to read the Alerts log to check what are the alerts being thrown

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the spell checker on the client resp. try another browser. There is a known bug (and as far as I know a patch as well) of Internet Explorer which causes it to take up huge amounts of RAM with an activated spell checker if you have quite a list of UI elements.